# How to get a value from my MySQL database to Android?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I know this topic has already a solution on stackoverflow. But for instance I can't use HttpClient to read a value from my MySQL database. So actually I am looking for a really simple code which can allow to read one value of a MySQL database. Do you have an example which works for API 24?

Comment: Why are you using HttpClient to read a value from MySQL database?

Comment: Please explain your question more clearly what you want to do.

Comment: First of all: Search for JDBC connection. Second: search why should i use an api for database access.
If you want some thing simple, try use https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/

Comment: I saw but I did not see any short examples so I am a little bit disappointed by your answers :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library called [jtds](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)
This will allow you to manage sql server connections in your Android app. However the comment is correct this will only work with MS SQL Server.

However I found this while I was digging, apparently one of the answers denotes that if you find the correct version of MySQL Connector/J you may be able to get it working. However the functionality may only be available in the target api version that the connection driver works with. [See SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044910/how-to-make-mysql-connector-j-working-on-android)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but right now I have no idea to do what I wanted to do. :/