# I can't add connector/j library in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, connector-j

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNNsN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2UF8.png)
I'm trying to link a database to my mobile application, but I can't find anywhere how to add a library. I created a libs folder in the app and uploaded a .jar file there, but Android Studio still doesn’t see this library. when I tried to add directly via grandle I got a lot of errors

at the beginning I wanted to use psql, but I didn’t find video lessons on this, I started using mysql and now I can’t connect.
Also, when I run a project with these methods, when I click on the button, my application crashes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZaRx.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not use images for documenting your code and errors as they are not searchable. Please search before asking. Do read [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/295004), [How to make MySQL Connector/J working on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25044910/295004) and [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)

Comment: Related [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700053/how-to-add-local-jar-file-dependency-to-build-gradle-file) and the `repositories {flatDir {...}}` is relevant.